# SQL Server: Tempdb: per Instance not per Database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

The tempdb system database is created by system per Instance or per Database on SQL Server?

I believe it is created per Instance is it true?

Kindly requested to guide!

Regards,

Comment: Didn't you google it? The tempdb system database is a global resource that is available to all users connected to the instance of SQL Server.. Here is the [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190768.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

It's per instance. Every instance will have 1 tempdb, which will be recreated every time SQL Server restarts.